# nifi freezes the flow unless there is some modification in List file

Tags: apache-nifi, marklogic

I am doing some test drive on Nifi and following the below link. The flow works fine and sends the output to ML database but if i want to run the flow again it doesnt' do anything. If i do some modification in listfile like in inputdirectory add slash/remove slash at the end and run it again it works. not sure if there is any setting that it is showing this behavior. How should i make it run which i click on start?

https://marklogic.github.io/nifi/step-by-step#add-querymarklogic-processor
Edited: Attaching the picture
first processor in the flow is ListFile Processor

[image]

[image]

Edit: Adding scheduling tab
[image]

Comment: What is the first processor in your flow? What is the scheduling configuration you defined for it?

Comment: Added the screenshot @daggett

Comment: What about scheduling?

Comment: are you getting file after listing? or you keep it as is in original directory? file supposed to be changed to get into the list next iteration of directory scanning...

Comment: What behavior do you expect from ListFile when you say - `if i want to run the flow again it doesnt' do anything`? How files are landing into the Input Directory? You have used Listing Strategy as Tracking Timestamps so already listed files will be skipped. For troubleshooting, clear the state of the ListFile processor and check whether same files are being listed at next run!

Comment: https://marklogic.github.io/nifi/step-by-step#add-querymarklogic-processor @VikramsinhShinde i am following the above link..

Comment: @daggett ...the file is not changed, it is not moved /deleted..

Comment: that is the issue. file must be new/changed to be listed by listfile. probably you are using incorrect processor? have a look at GetFile , FetchFile. or use a script